# Error on large dimension value - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mat' was corrupted

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, access-violation

I am getting following error:

"**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mat' was corrupted**" after giving result in console.

However, What I observed that, CreateMatrix function ***throws Access violation.. for larger matrix dimensions. For e.g. worked for 5x7 and did NOT work for 50 x 70.*** How ?

Program is just to create Matrix (initialize) and Set + print Matrix element.

***Also, the caveat in problem is that I've been asked NOT to use anything like "Matrix* mat.." inside main(). Otherwise, solution is straight-forward.***

I hope, you get my problem.

More detailed code:

```
struct Matrix
{
    int width;
int height;
int* data;
};
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

int main()
{
    Matrix mat, *matP;

    //1. Things that Works...
    matP = CreateMatrix(&mat,700,500);         
    SetValue(matP,500,600,-295);
    int val=GetValue(matP,500,600);
    printf("%d\n",val); 


    //2. Things that does NOT work... !!!
    CreateMatrix(&mat,700,500); // this is C-style "Call-By-Reference" CreateMatrix2()
    SetValue(&mat,500,600,-295); // ERROR in this function, while setting matrix element
    val=GetValue(&mat,500,600);

    printf("%d\n",val); 
}


void SetValue(Matrix* mat,int row,int col,int value)
{
    *(mat[(mat->width*(row-1)) + (col-1)].data) = value;// <------ ERROR here

    // Unhandled exception at... Access violation writing location 0x000001f4
}

Matrix * CreateMatrix(Matrix *mat,int width,int height)
{        
    // mat = (Matrix*)malloc(width*height*(sizeof(Matrix))); // As told by Salgar
    mat->height = height;
    mat->width = width;

    for(int i=0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            mat[width*i + j].width = width;
            mat[width*i + j].height = height;
            mat[width*i + j].data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit weird code: why you use mat (set height and width) and then malloc's the memory? Previous content of the matrix may be destroyed

Comment: There is no need to cast a result of `malloc()` in C.

Comment: @maverik, Edited post, please take a look. But, still "things does NOT work..." (thanks for bring'n it to notice)

Comment: Is this behavior (Access violation error for large matrix dimension) related to Program's Stack allocation or am I missing something ?

Comment: Here's another error i'm facing after getting result is: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mat' was corrupted

Comment: Problem answered... thanks all for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference it correctly,
 
Instead of:
    *(mat[(mat->width*(row-1)) + (col-1)].data) = value;// <------ ERROR here

mat->data[(mat->width*(row-1)) + (col-1)] = value;// <------ NO ERROR here

Also, your CreateMatrix function is totally messed up

> ```
> Matrix * CreateMatrix(Matrix *mat,int width,int height)
> {        
>     // mat = (Matrix*)malloc(width*height*(sizeof(Matrix))); // As told by Salgar
>     mat->height = height;
>     mat->width = width;
>
>     for(int i=0; i < height; i++ )
>     {
>         for(int j=0; j < width; j++ )
>         {
>             mat[width*i + j].width = width;
>             mat[width*i + j].height = height;
>             mat[width*i + j].data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Use something like this instead:

```
Matrix * CreateMatrix(Matrix *mat,int width,int height)
{        
    mat->height = height;
    mat->width = width;
    mat->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * height * width);
}
```

Comment: Yes , I did that change. However, I still facing error, that I've updated in posted question.

Comment: See, when you are writing `mat[index]`,  you are trying to access memory address at the address of mat + index * sizeof(Matrix). Now, this address would be on the stack, as mat variable is on the stack. 
So, if you don't fix it, you would be getting stack corrupted sort of a message.

Comment: So, I was getting stack's error due to limitation of stack allocation I was ignoring ?

Comment: I appreciate your answer.. Many Many thanks for your prompt and exact reply I was looking for ! :)

Comment: @bharat.chandak100: I don't really understand what you mean. You were getting stack error, because, you were modifying the contents of the stack which were out of your bounds. When you wrote `Matrix mat;` you asked the compiler for **12 bytes of space**, but after the first or second reference, all your references were out of your limits (as explained above).

You may want to read more about Buffer Overflows to understand how is the stack protected from overwriting and why: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Comment: When I say buffer overflows, you should read this one specifically, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to `mat` on this line:

```
 mat = (Matrix*)malloc(width*height*(sizeof(Matrix)));
```

It is changing the *Locally scoped copy of `mat`* And hence nothing is happening to the mat you have declared on the stack in the calling function.

You need to pass a pointer to a pointer and not declare one on the stack, as you can't overwrite that with something you're declaring on the heap.

```
Matrix* mat;
CreateMatrix(&mat,700,500);

Matrix * CreateMatrix(Matrix **mat,int width,int height)
{
   ...
   *mat = malloc(etc)
   ...
}
```

Comment: The caveat in problem is that I've been asked NOT to use "Matrix* mat.." Otherwise, solution is straight-forward.

Comment: That whole CreateMatrix function doesn't make sense. You need to malloc the `mat->data` variable, not the `mat` itself. That way you can use your original function signature.

Comment: yes, I did remove that malloc for mat obj. But, unfortunately I observed that, CreateMatrix function throws Access violation.. for larger matrix dimensions. For e.g. worked for 5x7 and did NOT work for 50 x 70. How ?

Comment: Is this behavior (Access violation error for large matrix dimension) related to Program's Stack allocation or am I missing something ?

Comment: ohh.. Another error I'm getting at end of program run: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mat' was corrupted."

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Matrix
{
int width;
int height;
int* data;
};
typedef struct Matrix Matrix;

int main()
{
Matrix mat, *matP;

//2. Things that does NOT work... !!!
CreateMatrix(&mat,700,500); // this is C-style "Call-By-Reference" CreateMatrix2()
SetValue(&mat,500,600,-295); // ERROR in this function, while setting matrix element
val=GetValue(&mat,500,600);

printf("%d\n",val); 

free(mat->data);
} 


void SetValue(Matrix* mat,int row,int col,int value)
{
*(mat[(mat->width*(row-1)) + (col-1)].data) = value;// <------ ERROR here

// Unhandled exception at... Access violation writing location 0x000001f4
}

void CreateMatrix(Matrix *mat,int width,int height)
{        
mat->height = height;
mat->width = width;
mat->data = (int*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(int));
}
```

If I understand the restriction you have is, not to use pointers in main function, So we declare a local variable and then pass its pointer, which gets the data pointer and width and height assigned to it.